# English Horn correcting flat G-Flat

Tags: fingering, english-horn

I just began playing the English Horn after playing oboe for the past 6 years. I have found that most of the notes are in tune, or close enough that I can correct with embouchure.

The main exception to this is the G-Flat right above the staff. This note, even when making extremely drastic adjustments with my embouchure, remains no less than 30 cents flat.

This may be because it is a cheap, school owned instrument or because of a not-so-great bocal (but I can't replace either).

Is there an alternate fingering or other way to compensate for this very flat G-Flat?

Answer (score 3):

High G-Flat- and the equivalent on the oboe, the high D-Flat- is a notoriously hard note to tune.  My advice: just play around.  Try opening some of the trill keys in addition to the normal fingering.  Lots of instruments require their own particular fingering for this note.

Answer (score 0):

You really do **not** want to try to compensate via embouchure, since some day you'll get a good instrument and don't want to have to unlearn it.  BTW, if the bocal were at fault, you'd expect all notes to be off, not just a single fingering.

I'm not familiar with Eng Horn fingering, but: if this note involves opening a hole (finger up, whatever),  then possibly you can compensate by lining the hole with a few layers of tape.  This narrows the opening and to a small extent will sharpen the pitch.

Comment: Changing the size of a hole is not a good idea, because there is no one hole that only affects the pitch of this G-Flat and no other note.  The high G-Flat is played as a fourth harmonic of the lowest G-Flat and doesn't have its own tone hole.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a digital tuner, so I presume you mean the note *sounding* as G-flat 5, but *written* as D-flat 6 for either oboe or English horn.

A website that I've found to be a useful resource for instruments that I can actually play — *The Woodwind Fingering Guide* offers the following [alternate fingering](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/oboe/ob_alt_3.html) describing it as "Good for English horn":

[image: Oboe fingering diagram "-23|45-c"]

This is just like the standard oboe fingering for D-flat 6, but with the middle finger on the lower hand added.